# Suddenly cannot pull changes from repository in my cpanel

Tags: git, repository, cpanel

I am using CentOS server. I've been using git version control on my cPanel to pull whenever there's a changes on my repository. But suddenly I got this error . Maybe this happen when I generate a new key on my SSH Access? I don't know but I'm new in using this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a lot of info there. Do you have logs so that we can see what happened in the fetch/pull action? If so, add them to the question.

Comment: @eftshift0 I think this happens after I generate a new key on my SSH access.

Comment: That would definitely explain.

Comment: but i just generate a key and didn't change anything on my repository.

Comment: If cPanel is picking up that new key, then you need to change it also in the remote.... my guess.

Comment: @eftshift0 I already did that but still nothing happens. Is there any other way to fix it and function it again just like before?

Comment: Take a look at the logs and see what they can tell you about the problem. Otherwise, it's just guessing (as educated as it might be :-))